# Python - SQL Effective way to update all rows in table

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update a sql table with lots rows using python. Suppose the table have three columns, (id BIGINT, key text, content text). I need update the "content" field of all rows based some function myfun on the "key". Myfun uses some web APIs and may take a little bit time.
So what I did is:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='xxx')
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.select_db("%s" % dbname)
cur.execute("select key from table")
results = cur.fetchall()
for result in results:
  txt = myfun(result[0])
  cur.execute("update posts set content = %s where key = %s", (txt, result[0]))
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

This works for me when the table is small. I am not sure whether it works if table have lots rows. Or is there any more effective way to update rows this case?

Thanks

Comment: can you describe/add-snippet of `myfun()` ?

Comment: I use myfun(keyword) to do some scrapy work, e.g., scrape content based on the "keyword" parameter on a website and save scraped content to the database. So I may periodically re-scrape the website and update all rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using innodb, you could commit it all in one transaction, setting foreign key checks, unique checks etc. to false, 
But did you check if the bottle neck is the mysql update command or the myfun function, if it's myfun, you should be focusing on optimizing that instead.

Are you making a synchronous call in myfun and waiting for the response? How about making it asynchronous with something like [unirest](http://unirest.io/python.html)